# Variable with x number of strings from list in Python

Tags: python, string, random

Say that I had a list containing 5 strings, and I wanted to print a random number of randomly generated strings from this list. Is there a simple way to do this?

I know multiple ways to print a single random string from this list, and multiple ways to print a set number of random strings from this set. The problem comes from wanting to print a random number of random strings from the list.

To get a set number of random strings (let's say 2) I would do the following:

```
 import random
 my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
 two_rand_strings = str(my_list[random.randint(0,4)]) + " " + str(my_list[random.randint(0,4)])
 print(two_rand_strings)
```

I assume I need to create some sort of function to generate a random number of strings but I am new to python and scratching my head.

Comment: Should each selected string be unique or can they be duplicated?

Comment: Good question, I should have specified. Ideally, each would be unique. However, I am interested in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API for that.

The [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module has several options to select from a population such as a list. And if you want use use the same separator for each item in the string result, you can `str.join` them.

```
import random
my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
unique = " ".join(random.sample(my_list, k=2))
nonunique = " ".join(random.choices(my_list, k=2))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you mean random number of random chosen strings this may help you:

```
import random

my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

randomCount = random.randint(0, 5)

myString = ""
for i in range(0, randomCount):
    myString = myString + " " + str(my_list[random.randint(0, 4)])

print(myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
i = 0 # set i (counter to zero)
my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e'] # your list
print_str = "" # define the printed variable
for x in my_list: # loop through your list
    i += 1 # increase counter by one
    print_str += x + " " # add new strings to the printed variable
    if i == 2: # when it reach the required number of strings, breaks the loop
        break

print(print_str) # print the strings
```